# How to create a precision recall curve from a random forest model?

Tags: r, random-forest, precision-recall

I am trying to create a precision recall curve from a random forest model based off of just the training data. It is similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/calculating-aupr-in-r), but I don't know the code to create the PR curve. See my reproducible example below (which is modified so it matches my personal dataset):

```html
#Load beaver2
View(beaver2)

#convert outcome into factor
beaver2 <- beaver2 %>% mutate(activ = ifelse(activ==0, "no","yes"))

#convert outcome to factor
beaver2$activ <- as.factor(beaver2$activ)

#create trControl
data_ctrl_null <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, savePredictions=T, sampling=NULL)

#create rf model
rf_model <- train(activ ~ ., data=beaver2, trControl = data_ctrl_null, method= "rf", preProc=c("center","scale"),metric="ROC", importance=TRUE)

#create precision recall curve
library("PRROC")
```

I want to use the `PRROC` package. How do I grab the predictions from the random forest model and create the PR curve? Note; I want to create the predictions on my training data; so imagine there is no testing data for predictions. Much appreciated for all the help!

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRROC/vignettes/PRROC.pdf, the scores are the predicted probabilites

Comment: when you have a model from caret, you normally do predict(...), so you can also predict a probability, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198668/how-to-predict-probabilities-for-a-target-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Load beaver2
View(beaver2)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

#convert outcome into factor
beaver2 <- beaver2 %>% mutate(activ = ifelse(activ==0, "no","yes"))

#convert outcome to factor
beaver2$activ <- as.factor(beaver2$activ)

#create trControl
data_ctrl_null <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, savePredictions=T, sampling=NULL)

#create rf model
rf_model <- train(activ ~ ., data=beaver2, trControl = data_ctrl_null, method= "rf", preProc=c("center","scale"),metric="ROC", importance=TRUE)

# predict using train data
predictions <- predict.train(rf_model)
test_data <- beaver2 %>% select(-activ) #instead of train data, use unseen test data here.
predictions <- predict(object = rf_model, newdata = test_data)
#add some artificial wrong predictions, otherwise perfect prediction, since we use train data as test
predictions[1] <- 'yes'
predictions[18] <- 'yes'
predictions[60] <- 'no'
predictions[61] <- 'no'
predictions[100] <- 'no'
confusion_Matrix <- table(Predictions = predictions, Reference = beaver2$activ)

#create precision recall curve
library("PRROC")

fg <- predictions[beaver2$activ == 'yes']
bg <- predictions[beaver2$activ == 'no']

pr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = fg, scores.class1 = bg, curve = T)
plot(pr)
```

See also the reply here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/calculating-aupr-in-r

Comment: Looking back on this a few days later, why does precision recall need to be made from test data when we can easily calculate ROC on train and test data? Running "predictions <- predict.train(rf_model)" gives an AUPRC=1.0...is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fixed on the PROC package, i can highly recommend evalm function from the MLeval package to you. It works very well and simple with caret.

In your case, all you need to do is

```
x <- evalm(rf_model )
x$roc #roc curve
x$stdres #model specs
x$cc #calibration plot
```

for your train data set. This code would work for your test data set:

```
test <- evalm(data.frame(pred, test.data$outcome))
test$roc
test$stdres
test$cc
```